# Regexp_like working on a debugger website but not working on Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I'm at work for a trigger which provide a "domain" for column `Molteplicità` in a table called `Partecipa` using a function.

The trigger I've created is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dominioMolteplicità
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON partecipa
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF moltepl_valido(:NEW.molteplicità) = 'f' THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Invalid type');
    END IF;
END;
```

which uses the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION moltepl_valido(mol VARCHAR2) RETURN CHAR IS
BEGIN
    IF regexp_like(LOWER(mol), '[\d]+\.\.[\*]|[\d]|[\*]') THEN
        RETURN 't';
    ELSE
        RETURN 'f';
    END IF;
END;
```

Table `Partecipa` has the following columns:

```
CodP INT,
molteplicità VARCHAR2,
codAss INT,
className VARCHAR2,
PRIMARY KEY (codP),
FOREIGN KEY (className) REFERENCES class(name),
FOREIGN KEY (codAss) REFERENCES associazione(cod)
```

When I execute the following statement

```
insert into Partecipa(molteplicità, className, codAss) 
values ('2', 'Impiegato', 42);
```

my trigger says "Invalid type" (function return false, but it should insert)

I get these errors:

> ORA-20002 INVALID TYPE
>
> ORA-06512: AT "dominioMolteplicità", line 3
>
> ORA-04088: ERROR DURING EXECUTION OF TRIGGER "dominioMolteplicità"

More over
When I execute the following statement

```
insert into Partecipa(molteplicità, className, codAss) 
values ('*..*', 'Impiegato', 42);
```

it inserts properly (but it should not according to [link](https://regex101.com/r/BfSt9j/3)

**Relevant Edit:**

I want my trigger to enforce the following values for column `Molteplicità`:

*accept (only these cases)*:

```
'n..m' (where n>=0, m > 0 and n<m)
'*' (where * is literally the character *)
'n..*' (where n>=0 and * is literally the character *)
'n' (where n>0)
```

*do not accept*:

```
'*..*' (where * is any character)
'*..n' (where * is literally the character * and for any value of n)
'n..m' (where n>=0, m > 0 and n>=m)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `RAISE_APPLICAZION_ERROR`.  If you have this, then the trigger may not be defined properly.

Comment: * means "anything" in regexp. If you want to refer to the * character, you will need to escape it. Your trigger throws an error when the validation returns 'f'. You will need to change that if you want invalid records to be inserted.

Comment: Even though I insert ESCAPE* in the regexp, the problem still exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the latest set of rules posted. Given that you want to validate the actual values of numbers when they're posted it is not possible to do this in a single regex expression (at least as far as I know):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION moltepl_valido(mol VARCHAR2) RETURN CHAR IS
BEGIN
    IF regexp_like(mol, '\d+\.\.\d+$')
        and to_number(regexp_substr(mol,'\d+', 1, 2)) > to_number(regexp_substr(mol,'\d+', 1, 1)) then
        RETURN 't';
    ELSIF regexp_like(mol, '^\d+$')
        and to_number(regexp_substr(mol,'\d+')) > 0 then
        RETURN 't';    
    ELSIF regexp_like(LOWER(mol), '(^\d+)\.\.\*$|^\*$') THEN
        RETURN 't';
    ELSE
        RETURN 'f';
    END IF;
END;
/
```

This accepts the following values of `molteplicità` ...

- `2..*`
- `23..*`
- `0..*`
- `2`
- `*`
- `2..3`
- `0..3`
- `23..32`
- `23`

... and rejects ...

- `2..A`
- `*..*`
- `A..B`
- `3..2`
- `2..2`

If these are not the rules you want to enforce please **edit your question** to include a complete set of requirements.

There is [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eff5919614c0e50c2c49c816e15eafb9).